# date: invalid option -- 'c'

Tags: linux, date, ssh, web-hosting

I'm trying to connect to the hosting via ssh. But have this problem:

```
$ ssh my_login@my_ip
my_login@my_ip's password: 
date: invalid option -- 'c'
Try `date --help' for more information.
Connection to my_ip closed.
```

What is it?

Comment: It would help if you say what hosting server you are using and its operating system. It looks like the server may be misconfigured. You might be able to get round this by adding `-t bash` or `-t sh` to the end of the command.

Comment: It is don`t help. Ubuntu, [Hosting](http://hehost.com.ua)

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect by other means, check you `.profile` and `.bashrc` (or `.kshrc`, depending on the default shell) for any date command.

The idea is to keep those files as lean/small as possible first, then add back their content in order to determine what causes this error message.